# Repetition of the last string when reading from .txt file C

Tags: c

This is the code, it reads from a file and then it prints what is written in that file. 
I don't know why but the last string of the file is readed twice.

> Code

```
FILE* src = fopen(name_email_src, "r");
if (src == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR source file not found");
}
while(fgets(buff_src, sizeof(buff_src), src) != NULL)
{
    fputs(buff_src, stdout);
}
fclose(src);
printf("%s", buff_src);
```

> This is the output:

```
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2017 21:32:46 +0100 (CET)
From: Rental <rental@house-rental.com>
To: me <me@upf.edu>
Message-ID: message2
Subject: Paga el alquiler ya.

Dear customer,

you are late in your payment, please pay or LEAVE!

Sincerely yours,
House rental
House rental
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Using the debugger to step through the program would quickly show you where the problem is.

Comment: Why does code contain `printf("%s", buff_src);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%s", buff_src);` is printing the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra call to `printf()` after your `while` loop:

```
while(fgets(buff_src, sizeof(buff_src), src) != NULL)
{
    fputs(buff_src, stdout); // prints each line
}
fclose(src);
printf("%s", buff_src); // prints buff_src which still holds the last line
```

Just remove this unnecessary call to `printf()` and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` reads line by line from the file. From the man page of `fgets()`

*If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.*

```
fgets(buff_src, sizeof(buff_src), src) /* read upto New line or EOF from src and store into buff_src */
```

when loop fails whatever `buff_src` contains that's been printed using last `printf` statement.